Crashlytics on iOS: sandbox file-read-data error
I using the latest version of Xcode (15.4)
and the latest version of Firebase (10.27.0) via cocoapods (linked statically)
When I try to build, I get this error:

Sandbox: bash(91670) deny(1) file-read-data
/Users/xxx/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/run

What is the reason and why did this come up only recently?
Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

I believe app sandboxing was enabled by default in Xcode 14. The suggestion is to provide input files to the run script which will be the directories the script will have access to read.
The configuration is described in the step 4-d from this document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#set-up-dsym-uploading
Another option would be disabling app sandboxing in case the above doesn't work. You can find this in "Build Settings".
